# Installing Java Card applet using ACR122

Tags: java, applet, nfc, javacard, acr122

I'm a newbie to Java Card technology, and I just started reading about it. I want to create a smart applet for my card. My goal is for it to work on card used contactlessly. 
I downloaded jar file (GlobalPlatformPro) to install *.cap file on card using NFC Card Reader ACR122. But unfortunately I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: apdu must be at least 2 bytes long
        at javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU.check(ResponseAPDU.java:73)
        at javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU.<init>(ResponseAPDU.java:67)
        at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(ChannelImpl.java:91)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.select(GlobalPlatform.java:203)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:334)
```

My first question is, is it possible to write an applet using this reader? And secondly how you would recommend doing this?

Comment: What kind of card are you using anyway? There isn't Global Platform on just any card.

Comment: Hi, @vojta I know that it's not necessary to hava card reader to write applet. I wanted to say that my goal is to write *.cap file on real card. I've just created an simple Java Card Project. Error was thrown when I was trying to install applet on card. I connected ACR122 reader to my PC, started terminal and run command: 'java -jar gp.jar -install applet.cap'
I'm using Mifare 1K Cards which was enclosed with reader. Should I buy another card?

Comment: @Krystian yes, buy another card. Mifare 1K is a simple data storage, there is no support for Java Card. Mifare is not programmable, it cannot run any custom code. Look for J2A081 by NXP, for example. Or any SIM by Gemalto.

Comment: @vojta Could you recommend me any contactless card?

Comment: @Krystian J3A081, J3E145, both by NXP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to upload an applet to a card, which does not support Global Platform nor Java Card. Mifare 1K is a simple data storage, it can hold some data you write in using its proprietary API. It cannot run any applets, this card is not "smart".

The error message says the response APDU is shorter than expected. Mifare responses do not follow ISO7816, the response status consists of just one byte only, although ISO7816 expects at least two byte long status word.

Look for another card. It should support JCOP, that is the keyword to search.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've already managed to install my applet on Virtual Device (provided with Java Card SDK). Could you provide me any valuable tutorial how to write applet's for Java card?

Comment: Recommend some good tutorials to you :   1.  http://ftp.cis.nctu.edu.tw/csie/Documents/Java/javacard/AppletDevelopersGuide.pdf               2.http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Hardware/Smart%20Card%20Handbook.pdf      3.  http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewforum.php?f=31     Hope these help

Comment: Javacard applet demo : http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=114